# JSON Data that provided by Spring-Boot-JPA with paging and sorting- For what?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot data, with jpa, and PagingAndSortingRepository

As known - that this kind of data mapping is represented by the browser, when using JPA.

[image: data on the browser]

For example when we are navigating to that page
http://localhost:8080/api

we're getting all the data that resides on the connected DB's.

So I'm not sure for what this mapping is good, since, if you want to filter the data, you need to use queries methods that you will create (at the repo) , and if you want to update/create/etc. , it's also not enough.

So the advantage is only that you can get the data with some pagination without filtering the data ?

(For [example](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/pagination-sorting-example/#:%7E:text=Learn%20to%20request%20and%20display,in%20tabular%20format%20in%20UI.) see here at the bottom of the tutorial)

*I don't think it's based opinion question, I want to hear on possible reasons, not only the best reason.

Comment: I don't see how the filtering and pagination are mutually exclusive.
Create and update methods ofcourse don't have pagination options, as those don't query sets of data.
Are you using the spring-data-jpa derived queries? (For reference, see example 5. on https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories as an example)

Comment: @PieterVandeperre-ACAGroup

Yes I'm using derived queries among the others. 
I didn't say it's mutually exclusive.

So for what exactly are those links are good? 
For cases that I want to get ALL the data, and I need pagination? 

Many times we want to first filter and then paging and sorting...